# Trying to write a trigger before delete on child to update a value in parent object

Tags: apex, trigger, update

Here's what I have.

Basically, if an opportunitylineitem is deleted, before it gets delete I need the probability field on opportunity to be set to 99. I can't seem to get it to work. What am I missing?

```
trigger BeforeDeleteProbability on OpportunityLineItem (before delete) {
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (OpportunityLineItem oli:trigger.old){
        oppIds.add(oli.opportunityId);
    }

    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppstoUpdate = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([Select Id, probability From Opportunity where id in: oppids]);
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli: Trigger.old){
        oppstoUpdate.get(oli.OpportunityId).probability = 99;
    }

    try {
        update oppsToUpdate.values();        
    }
    catch(Exception Ex){
        system.debug(Ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of tidying up your code here to be consistent in style and indentation (and that did involve removing some completely blank lines).  Well-formatted code helps other people read your code, which makes it easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to take a guess at what your issue is, I'd say that you're probably getting a `Duplicate object in list` error.

You're not seeing that error because you are smothering any exceptions you encounter with that try/catch block.

I'd recommend removing the try/catch, or at the very least adding some additional debugging so that you can see that an exception was encountered in your debug logs.

You also don't need to query for the `Opportunity` records to update them. You can take advantage of the SObject constructor allowing you to specify the Id.

Getting back to my suspected error, you can solve that by using a `Map<Id, Opportunity>` to store the Opportunity records that you're trying to update.

All in all, your trigger might end up looking like this

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppstoUpdate = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
for(OpportunityLineItem oli: Trigger.old){
    oppstoUpdate.put(oli.OpportunityId, new Opportunity(Id = oli.OpportunityId, Probability = 99));
}

// DML won't work on a Map directly, so we need to get a list of the values
//   contained in the map, and give that to the DML operation instead.
// Since we're using a Map here, we should be guaranteed to not run into a
//  "duplicate value in list" error
update oppsToUpdate.values();
```